# Descomponer un numero en todos lo que tiene dentro en python

Tags: python

Necesito pedir un número aleatorio, y que luego, me devuelva todos los números de su interior, por ejemplo:
Si pongo **4**, que el programa me devuelva: **1,2,3,4**.

¿Alguna idea?

Un ejemplo del programa:

```
numero_dado = int(input("Inserte un número")
```

Luego hacer esta operación, e imprimir el resultado:

```
print(numeros_finales)
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Buen día,

Podrías hacer algo así:

```
numero_dado = int(input('Inserte un número'))
print(*range(1,numero_dado+1))
```

Recuerda que `range()` tiene como argumentos el valor inicial y el límite del rango, pero el límite no se incluye por lo que tienes que sumar 1

Comment: Recuerda no hacerle la tarea a la gente. Ahora es posible que el OP se lleve la tarea hecha sin haber aprendido nada.